# Can protobuf service method return primitive type?

Tags: protocol-buffers, rpc, protobuf-c

I'm trying to use Google protobuf and i 'm having the next descriptions:

**message.proto** file:

```
message Request {
   required int32 id = 1;
   optional string value = 2;
}
```

**service.proto** file:

```
import "message.proto";

service Service {
    rpc request (Request) returns (bool);
}
```

I'm trying to generate c++ sources and getting an error:

> $ protoc service.proto --cpp_out=/tmp/proto/build
>
> service.proto:4:40: Expected message type.

Do i have to return user-defined types only? Are primitive (like `bool` or `string`) supported?  Can i use primitive types as service method argument (instead of `Request` in my example)?

Comment: How about

`message Bool {
  bool status = 1;
}`

Answer (score 55, accepted):

No, you cannot use a primitive type as either the request or response. You must use a message type.

This is important because a message type can be extended later, in case you decide you want to add a new parameter or return some additional data.

Comment: This is a shortcoming IMHO compared to other architectures for defining services. For example, WCF supports primitive return types. The argument that a message is open for extensibility seems a masking of Protobuf's shortcomings.

Comment: @ToreAurstad It would be pretty easy to modify protobuf such that it allowed primitive types here. Not doing so is an intentional design decision.

Answer (score 10):

You can return scalar datatypes like bool, int, etc by making use of [wrappers.proto](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/wrappers.proto)

**service.proto** file:

```
import "message.proto";
import "google/protobuf/wrappers.proto";

service Service {
    rpc request (Request) returns (.google.protobuf.BoolValue); 
}
```

Answer (score 9):

If you want to return a primitive type, wrap it in a `message` and return it:

```
message Name {
  string name = 1;
}
```

In case you don't want to return anything, `void` I mean, you can just create an empty message:

```
message Void {} 

message Name {
  string name = 1;
}

..
service MyService{
  rpc MyFunc(Name) returns (Void);
}
```

Comment: Void is already available as: import "google/protobuf/empty.proto";